# I want to find $\angle BAD$.

Tags: geometry, angle

[image]

$ \angle BDC = 120°$, $\angle BEC = 160°$. I want to find $\angle BAD$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha = \angle BAD = \angle CAD$, $\beta = \angle ABD = \angle EBD$, $\gamma = \angle ACD = \angle ECD$.

The total of the angles in the quadrilateral $BACE\,$ is
$$
2\alpha + 2\beta + 2\gamma + 200^\circ = 360^\circ,
$$
so
$$
\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 80^\circ.
$$
The total of the angles in quadrilateral $BDCE\,$ is
$$
\beta + 120^\circ + \gamma + 200^\circ = 360^\circ,
$$
so
$$
\beta + \gamma = 40^\circ.
$$
Subtracting this from the previous result, $\alpha = 40^\circ$.